# What is the equivalent and simple jQuery code for following Javascript code

Tags: jquery

Here is javascript code

```
var getSubmit = getClass("submit"),
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

getSubmit[rand].click();

function getClass(className) {
    var a = [];
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for ( var i = 0, j = els.length ; i < j ; i++ ) {
        if (els.item(i).className.indexOf(className) != -1)
        a.push(els.item(i));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: why you need eqiv jQuery code when you have built with pure js?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: While I agree that it'd be an overkill to include jQuery only for this, if jQuery is already in the project, there's no need to have a 7 line function to write something that jQuery supports out of the box.

Comment: If you're not planning to use other jQuery resources, just stay with the Vanilla. Is it working? If so, good.

Comment: @praveen I guess this code is too much just to click on a random submit on a page where tere are multiple submits. So I was looking for short and simple .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>That's basically:</s>

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
$('[class~="' + rand + '"]').click();
```

Sorry, I misread your original code. The code you'd want looks more like this:

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
$('.submit').eq(rand).click();
```

Comment: Thank you david for nice explaination but unfortunately both of the answers are not working when I run them in firefox console i got following output
$('.button-' + rand).click();
Object[]

Comment: What do you mean by saying you get that output? Please give more context and some HTML. [The code works](http://jsfiddle.net/S7NGh/). The second snippet only works if your items actually are called `button-X`. You need to make sure jQuery is installed.

Comment: I mean when i run the code instead of going to next page i got that objec[].Here is relevant html code 
<input type="submit" name="addToCartButtonSelected" value="Select flight &gt;" class="submit">
There are multiple submits but only one code for all those submits.
I know this html code is not great but I can not edit this.

Comment: Thank you david the modified code is working fine. General question can you suggest me some online links so I can become expert in javascript and jquery ?

Comment: Glad it helped. You couldl always check out [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/)